# Very strange behavior in Javascript. Code running out of order

Tags: javascript

I have trouble describing this since I cannot recreate any isolated instances. Setting a boolean inside an if statement gets set before it ever reaches the if statement.  I thought this had to do with the console having the log appear out of order, but I can now see the result in the j for loop on occurring unless I remove `notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].played = true`.

```
if(shapesNotes.length === 2){
    if(shapesNotes[1].trans.all.combined.length == 2){
        console.log("troubled value = " + shapesNotes[1].trans.all.combined[1].played)
    }

}

function setTranspositionsForAllNotes(notesObj,debugIndex){

    for(var i=0; i<notesObj.trans.all.combined.length; ++i){
        var transNoteAt = notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].noteAt
        var transPlayed = notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].played
        
        console.log("debugIndex = " + debugIndex + "   i = " + i)
        console.log("notesObj.trans.all.combined.length = " +notesObj.trans.all.combined.length)
        console.log("notesObj.trans.all.combined["+i+"].played = " + notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].played)
        console.log("shapesNotes["+debugIndex+"].trans.all.combined["+i+"].played = " + shapesNotes[debugIndex].trans.all.combined[i].played)

        console.log("noteAt = "  + noteAt + " transNoteAt = "  + transNoteAt)

        if(transPlayed === false && 
           noteAt >= transNoteAt){
           
           var transInterval = notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].interval

           for(var j=0; j<notesObj.trans.array.length; ++j){
             notesObj.trans.array[j] += transInterval
             notesObj.trans.freqsPlusTrans[j] = getFrequencyPlusTranspositionForFreqIndex(notesObj,j)
           }
           
           console.log("transInterval = " + transInterval + " for " + debugIndex + "   i = " + i)
          

           notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].played = true
           
        
        }
    
    }
        
}

var debugIndex = 0;
shapesNotes.forEach(function(shapeNotes) {
    setTranspositionsForAllNotes(shapeNotes,debugIndex)
            
    debugIndex+=1
});
```

Just to include what my log shows, here it is:

```
1980 troubled value = false
1981 debugIndex = 0   i = 0
1982 notesObj.trans.all.combined.length = 2
1983 notesObj.trans.all.combined[0].played = false
1984 shapesNotes[0].trans.all.combined[0].played = false
1986 noteAt = 0.008333333333333333 transNoteAt = 0
1998 transInterval = 0 for 0   i = 0
1981 debugIndex = 0   i = 1
1982 notesObj.trans.all.combined.length = 2
1983 notesObj.trans.all.combined[1].played = false
1984 shapesNotes[0].trans.all.combined[1].played = false
1986 noteAt = 0.008333333333333333 transNoteAt = 0
1998 transInterval = 2 for 0   i = 1
1981 debugIndex = 1   i = 0
1982 notesObj.trans.all.combined.length = 2
1983 notesObj.trans.all.combined[0].played = false
1984 shapesNotes[1].trans.all.combined[0].played = false
1986 noteAt = 0.008333333333333333 transNoteAt = 0
1998 transInterval = 0 for 1   i = 0
1981 debugIndex = 1   i = 1
1982 notesObj.trans.all.combined.length = 2
1983 notesObj.trans.all.combined[1].played = true
1984 shapesNotes[1].trans.all.combined[1].played = true
1986 noteAt = 0.008333333333333333 transNoteAt = 0
```

Notice my "troubled value" is set to false for shapeNotes[1] for combined[1] according to the log, but when it reaches that in my first for loop, it is immediately set to true somehow and the j for loop inside or the console log never transpires. Oddly, the boolean setting `notesObj.trans.all.combined[i].played = true` inside the `transPlayed === false && noteAt >= transNoteAt` conditional takes place immediately, and at the same time none of the other code inside that conditional is performed, even if I set a breakpoint.

Comment: Is it possible that two entries in the array refer to the same object, one that you have already set its played property to true?

Comment: That sounds likely to me - the naming (`all.combined`) suggests that they might be the same object reference.

Comment: Does this return true?

`shapesNotes[0].trans.all.combined[1] === shapesNotes[1].trans.all.combined[1]`

Comment: just as a test: use semicolons at the end of each line/function/block of code (as intended).
I'm curious to see if it changes anything.
* of course: save a copy before...

Comment: Yes @CoryDanielson that returns true. I guess maybe I have an object reference instead of the actual boolean value?

Comment: I tracked it down to concat being the culprit. If used twice with one array with two other arrays, those arrays must hold references, so if one is changed, it also affects the other. Not using concat anymore.

Comment: The objects inside the arrays are the same reference - concat will return new array references though

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should change ++i to i++

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion, but unfortunately that does not have any effect.